# Applying a for loop on rows that meet certain conditions in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am looking to apply two different for loops on a single dataframe.

The data I have is taken from a PDF and looks like this upon reading into a DataFrame

```
   Output
```

| Summary | Prior Years | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total Value 3,700 | 110 | - | - | - | 5 | NaN | - | - | - | - | -- | 3,815 |
| Total Value | 115 100 | - | - | - | 10 | NaN | - | - | - | - | -- | 225 |

The expected table output is

```
Expected Output
```

| Summary | Prior Years | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total Value | 3,700 | 110 | - | - | - | 5 | - | - | - | - | -- | 3,815 |
| Total Value | 115 | 100 | - | - | - | 10 | - | - | - | - | -- | 225 |

To resolve the errors from the original output I did as follows

```
   test.loc[:,"1":"5"]=test.loc[:,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)
   test[['Summary','Prior Years']]=test['Summary'].str.strip().str.extract(r'(\D*).*?([\d\,\.]*)' )
```

and

```
    test.loc[:,"1":"5"]=test.loc[:,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)
    test[['Prior Years', '1']]=test['Prior Years'].str.split(' ',expand=True)
```

These solve the respective issues in both columns when isolated but I am looking to utilize both these conditions simultaneously

When I attempt to write 'for' loops using these conditions above, it affects the whole dataframe, rather than just the row where individual conditions are met

An example of this is

```
for i in test.loc[:,'Summary']:
    if len(i)>12:
       test.loc[:,"1":"5"]=test.loc[:,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)
       test[['Summary','Prior Years']]=test['Summary'].str.strip().str.extract(r'(\D*).*?([\d\,\.]*)' )
```

Which then outputs

```
Output
```

| Summary | Prior Years | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total Value | 3,700 | 110 | - | - | - | 5 | - | - | - | - | -- | 3,815 |
| Total Value |  | 115 100 | - | - | - | 10 | - | - | - | - | -- | 225 |

I am using the string length criteria as the hit for the for loop as the 'Summary' Column and 'Prior Years' Column will have fairly uniform str lengths

Answer (score 0):

Right now your operations are affecting the whole column. If you loop through the index instead, you can limit the operation to just the rows you want to change:

```
for idx in test.index:
    if len(test.loc[idx, "Summary"]) > 12:
       test.loc[idx,"1":"5"] = test.loc[idx,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)
       test.loc[idx, ['Summary','Prior Years']] = test.iloc[idx, 'Summary'].str.strip().str.extract(r'(\D*).*?([\d\,\.]*)' )
    
    if len(test.loc[idx, "1"]) > 5:
        test.loc[idx,"1":"5"] = test.loc[idx,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)
        test.loc[idx, ['Prior Years', '1']] = test.loc[idx, 'Prior Years'].str.split(' ',expand=True)
```

If this code is too slow, it's also possible to vectorize this:

```
mask = test.Summary > 12
test.loc[mask,"1":"5"] = test.loc[mask,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)
test.loc[mask, ['Summary','Prior Years']] = test.iloc[mask, 'Summary'].str.strip().str.extract(r'(\D*).*?([\d\,\.]*)' )

mask = test["1"] > 5
test.loc[mask,"1":"5"] = test.loc[mask,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)
test.loc[mask, ['Prior Years', '1']] = test.loc[mask, 'Prior Years'].str.split(' ',expand=True)
```

Comment: This gives me the error "No axis named 1 for object type Series"

Comment: Remove `axis=1` or try running the vectorized version